# Autoincrement PK in JDeveloper

Tags: sql, auto-increment, oracle-adf, jdeveloper

So I'm working on a database application in JDeveloper, and one of the requirements is that the user doesn't need to manually enter a unique PK when creating a new object through a web form.

I've done my online searches for about two hours now, and I know that many people have solved this problem in the past.  But I'm having a hard following their solutions.

I've only started using JDeveloper, ADF/JSF/Facelets, and SQL less than a week ago, so I'd really appreciate step-by-step instructions.

Answer (score 0):

Check out my groovy sample at http://tompeez.wordpress.com/2011/09/02/using-groovy-expression-to-set-a-primary-key-with-a-sequence-number/
Which shows you how to use a groovy expression to do your use case.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your help Timo.  I actually didn't realize that you needed to create a sequence, so I wasn't able to work very far through your example.

I did eventually figure my problem out here:  http://sathyam-soa.blogspot.com/2012/07/adf-db-sequence-using-db-trigger.html

It spells out each step, with pictures, in creating a sequence, setting up auto-increment, and putting auto-increment functionality into a page.